# Alloy Analyzer 4.1.10- Generting Large datasets

Tags: alloy

I am new to Alloy. I want to generate large data sets with the help of Alloy, but I am not sure how to do it. 
I am able to generate data in small amount. But want to generate large amount of data which is unique.
I am using run command currently. And its perfectly fine, if I get data in format of Name_0, Name_1.. (for First Name)
Any tip in this regard will be a great help.

Comment: I guess you need to describe a bit more what you modeled and what you use to generate samples. Do you use the `run` function? I think the normal way Alloy is not very good for generating sample/test data if you do not capture all properties of the fields in your model (think "Firstname"). In that case you would rather generate sample data programmatically and only check it with Alloy.

Comment: Alloy 4.9.10 does not exist

Comment: Hi eces, yes I am using run command and running my .als file through java. It is OK for me even if I get data in Name_0, Name_1 format.

Comment: Aleksandar, Yes you are right. I am using 4.1.10 version. By mistake I wrote it the other version.